# show download button after countdown is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, download, countdown

I am working on my wordpress project and my idea that someone can download a file after the countdown is done (as we all know that aproach from multiple sites...).
I already have the countdown made and successfully working, but I dont know how to implement the "download" function.
Here is the link for countdown I have now:
https://jsfiddle.net/96Lkoh42/

Maybe somehow replace this part of the code?:
`newSubMessage:"and should be back online in a few minutes..."};`
(It is at the and of .js)

Comment: The script is pretty much minified, making the testing hard. Try to find the original plugin, include it and initialize it properly. After you find it you can check its docs and look for an callback after the countdown.

Comment: Sorry, It is here: https://jsfiddle.net/deLpu7jj/27/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like knutesten said.....you can do that in endEvent() function

i have edit your jsfidlle for working example(i edit the timezone for testing only).here `jsfiddle` https://jsfiddle.net/deLpu7jj/28/

Answer (score 1):

If you add an a-tag for you download in the html that is hidden you can show it when the countdown is done (ie. in your endEvent-function)

```
// html
<a id="download" href="..." style="display: none" download>Download</a>

// js
function endEvent() {
  $('#download').show();
}
```